Exponential polynomials with infinite number of roots
An (ordered) exponential field is a structure $(F, +, \cdot, 0, 1, <, \exp^{(1)})$ such that $((F, +, \cdot, 0, 1, <)$ is an ordered field an $\exp$ is an isomorphism of ordered abelian groups $(F, +, 0, <)$ and $(\{x \in F| x > 0\}, \cdot, 1, <)$. Roughly speaking, an exponential polynomial in the exponential field $F$ is a term in the corresponding language with parameters from $F$ (see [1] for the precise definitions). It is known from [1] that if $F$ has Rolle's property for all exponential polynomials and the additional property $\exp(x) \ge 1 + x$ for all $x \in F, then every nonzero exponential polynomial has only a finite number of roots.
I wonder whether the result holds in the absence of Rolle's property? My question is motivated by the following: what exponential fields are embeddable in exponential fields with Rolle's property? with intermediate value property? There is a result in [2] concerning such a question about intermediate value property, but only for exponential polynomials without iterated exponentiation.
[1] L. van den Dries. Exponential rings, exponential polynomials and exponential functions. Pacific Journal of Mathematics, 113, 1984.
[2] B. I. Dahn, H. Wolter. On the theory of exponential fields. Mathematical Logic Quarterly 29 (9):465-480, 1983
